# ReSharper ctorp - wth is that and where do I find it?

Tags: resharper, code-snippets

I really crave to create some funky snippets for my personal use and I want them to work similarly to ReSharper's ctorp. However I found out ctorp is not snippet and probably it is not Live Template either. Does someone can tell me what is this 'snippet' is and (if) where I can find its source code?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you really crave to do so then write your own resharper plugin. ctorp is so called generative completion. [Here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/sdk/Features/Completion.html) you can have a look for more information and ideas where to go next.